Can we construct a CPA-secure scheme with a PRNG and a random key?
I'm going through Katz and Lindell, currently at the part where they introduce pseudorandom permutations, and I was wondering this: given a PRNG, could we construct a CPA-secure scheme as follows?

The key $k$ is secret and chosen uniformly as usual.
A value $r$ is chosen uniformly. A derived key $k'$ is computed as $k' = k \oplus r$. ($k$ and $r$ are the same size.)
Compute the ciphertext as $c = \langle r, G(k') \oplus m \rangle$, where $G$ is a PRNG.

That is, it's the same construction as for an EAV-secure scheme but the seed to the PRNG is random with each invocation to $\mathrm{Enc}_k$.  This still uses nondeterminism to encrypt messages.

The security guarantee of a standard PRG holds when it is called on independently random seeds. Your construction violates these "terms of service" by invoking $G$ on seeds that are related by a known xor. You need
$$ G(k \oplus r_1), G(k \oplus r_2), \ldots, G(k \oplus r_n)$$
to be pseudorandom, when $k$ is uniform and secret, and the $r_i$'s are uniform and known to the adversary. This property is called correlation robustnessness, and it is also used in the famous IKNP03 paper and many followups.
Just knowing that $G$ is a PRG doesn't guarantee that it has the desired correlation robustness property. A simple counterexample is any $G$ that includes bits of the seed directly in the output. For example, suppose the first output bit of $G(s)$ is equal to the first bit of $s$. This property does not prevent $G$ from being a PRG, but it does prevent correlation robustness -- the first bit of $G(k \oplus r_i)$ depends only on the first bit of $r_i$, which the adversary knows.
